# Search engines ignoring meta description content and showing footer

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, meta-tags, seo

I have a site that is very simple and has mostly images and a login form and a link to signup. No actual text exist in the body except for the footer which shows the link to usage terms and copyright notice.

My site is currently showing up on search engine results with the footer content showing instead of what I put in the `<meta name="description"...>` tag. Why is this?

How can I not allow the search engines to index my site with the footer content showing? Or at least show the meta description first? Do I need to put some text in the form of a title attribute or alt attribute somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As +Filburt pointed out, you could add your site to Webmaster Tools which will offer you valuable information about your site's presence on the web and in the Google Search results. It may also provide you hints about what do we think about your meta descriptions :)

Generally, you will want to

- write the meta description to be as natural as possible, don't stuff keywords in it,
- describe the page's content accurately in this tag,
- and to have a unique meta description for each page.

While we can't guarantee that the meta description that you provided will be used as search result snippets, following the above tips will greatly increase the chance.

Here are some more information about the meta description tag: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35264

Comment: yes. I've looked through that link and have changed my meta tags :)

Comment: Waiting for the changes to apply. What should I do in the case Google doesn't choose the meta description tags?

Comment: And how long does it take for Google to reindex the site with the new snippet? Webmaster tools said it the robots.txt was downloaded 1 hour ago, which I assume the site has been crawled. But the SERP still shows the old snippet with the footer.

Comment: Usually when we think that there's something up with your meta descriptions, we will report it in Webmaster Tools. That's a good reason to verify your site. As for how much time it takes to reindex a site, there's no good answer for that. First of all, we recrawl sites per page and we don't usually recrawl all the pages from a site in one batch. Also, it depends on many things how much time  it takes to reindex a specific *page*. If it's a homepage or if the content changes often on a page, we'll revisit that page more often than pages that change only once in 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

It works to some extent to use `<meta name="description" />` but Google will complain (and choose to ignore it) when every page has the same description.

If you are interested in how Google deals with your site you could sign up for their [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) - they offer a good starting point for SEO-ing your site.

You could add content invisible to your visitor but Google checks this and considers hidden content as cheating for page rank because this used to be a common SEO technique.

Comment: +1 for Webmaster Tools but was tempted to also -1 for even mentioning hidden text :)

Comment: Why would you downvote for mentioning that hidden text is a no-no if the OP explicitly asks about in a comment? Not talking about it doesn't make it stop. Afaik Google does a good job at weeding out those pages trying to game page rank.

Comment: Was kidding with downvote, I gave you +1 :) When I started to read that sentence I almost had a heart attack.

Answer (score 0):

`meta` tags were a failure and have been <del>broadly ignored ever since the Google era began</del> [picked-up again with enthusiasm](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35264).

The problem was, humans would put stale, inaccurate, or irrelevant information in the meta tags. This was fifteen years ago when cataloging the Internet still seemed feasible.

Google came along and decided that what a web page *actually* says was more useful. Everybody else followed suit shortly after.

Now people are trying human-authored metadata again, they're calling it the "semantic web". My hopes are not high.

Comment: So how should I prevent the site from being indexed with the footer content as the description? What content can I add in the body that will show up in the search engine results but not "viewable" to the human user?